# Themes look strange, only window borders applied

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome-shell

Installed debian with gnome shell (3.20.2). Added a couple themes but they don't look right at all when I switch to them. Any theme except Adwaita appears show the window border ok, but the internal controls seem to fall back to some default style.

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZP4x.jpg)

I ran into this before and can't for the life of me remember what I did to resolve it (maybe a missing package or some env setting...).

- installed gtk2-engines-murrine
- user themes extension is enabled

still no go :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was an update to Gnome just recently (4/2016) in 3.20 that broke themes. You need to go get the latest updated theme (if available).

> There was a GTK update yesterday, that broke all your themes, that's
>   it. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=211154